# Geodesics with a normal distribution

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, geodesic, general-relativity

I'm working with the Desmos 3D calculator and I want to find the geodesic across some manifold currently I have a generalized equation for a generalized 3D distribution curve: $$f(x, y) = ab^{-{\left(\left(x-x_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(y-y_{1}\right)^{2}\right) \over c}} $$ with external variables $a, b, c, x_1,$ and $y_1$. I want know how I would find or approximate the geodesic of this graph (or any other manifold). I am currently trying to obtain the distance between some point $p$ and another point $p_1$ on our function $f(x,y)$ where the distance between $p$ and $p_1$ the distance is as small as possible. I plan to use this to iterate point $p$ by increasing it's $x$ and $y$ values by some amount, finding point $p_1$, moving point $p$ to point $p_1$,taking $p$'s last position and using it as a vector to find it's next position, increasing it by this vector, and then restarting from finding point $p_1$ though I don't know if this will work. any and all help is greatly appreciated, and I will provide a link to the graph I currently have if you need further understanding.

Comment: along with this, how would I put the Einstein Field Equations in terms of mass, radius, etc?

Comment: Where is the semi-Riemannian metric?

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't know what that is. this math is probably over my head but i still find it interesting. could you tell me what the semi-riemannian metric and how does it affect what i mentioned?

Comment: I don't know what your "negative 3 dimensional distribution curve" means. You have the equation of a surface in $3$-space. Finding the geodesics on a surface with the distance coming from the induced metric in $3$-space is a very complicated question. Even if you take $z=e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$, which has rotational symmetry, it will be hard enough to start. You should look at some undergraduate differential geometry texts and see the equations for geodesics. Your mixing the physics into this just makes it harder.

Comment: Sorry, i meant a 3 dimensional negative distribution curve, I will look into geodesics and see what I can learn, as I don't know much on the topic. thsnk you

Comment: This is sort of a long shot, but is the question motivated by the pop-science picture of "empty spacetime" as a flat sheet of rubber and a "spacetime containing mass" as a stretched sheet with ball bearings (or whatever) sitting on it, and the function in the question describes the shape of this stretched sheet...?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang sort of in a way, yes. I'm not simulating a 3D phyics body simulation, i want to simulate a 2 dimensional physics sim but I'm using the 3rd dimension to visualize the strength of the gravitational field (the depth of the 'stretched' space time). I understand that in a 3D simulation that this would be inaccurate as the body would not only have a gravitational field that acted in one direction, but all 3 spacial dimensions, sort of 'bending' grid lines in it's direction. If I've messed anything up let me know

Comment: I'm still vague on the question, but there's a risk of conceptually associating a coordinate grid and a family of geodesics. Cartesian coordinates in Euclidean geometry are misleading that way, because the two concepts happen to coincide. <> There's also a risk of assuming arbitrary 2-D geometry can be "effected" (or _isometrically embedded_) in 3-space. <> That's all to say, not sure anything is messed up, but even with limited understanding I'm uncertain of the question's foundations. [...]

Comment: My best guess is, you want to model a curved spacetime using a Riemannian metric, and are interested in plotting geodesics ("straight paths"). There's a well-known system of two ODEs, the geodesic equations for a surface, that accomplishes this _intrinsically_ in the geometry of the plane; numerical solution is straightforward. <> The 3-D aspect involves _extrinsic_ geometry, namely "isometric embedding" of an abstract surface in 3-space; that involves solving PDEs, and is correspondingly more vexing numerically. @TedShifrin has a free textbook that contains details of all this.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang  I didn't know how to phrase it, but I believe that's correct! I'll cefinitely be studying the textbook and will try to make sense of it and use it's info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As clarified in the comments, the question answered below is "How can I plot geodesics on a surface in three-space, assuming we have a parametrization?"

<>

Here's a sketch that follows standard development of a differential geometry course. A bare-bones summary may be found at the bottom. It may be worth reading that first.

Page numbers and notation match Ted Shifrin's *Differential Geometry* [Open Math Notes](https://www.ams.org/open-math-notes/omn-view-listing?listingId=110755) dated April 2021.

### Parametrization

$\newcommand{\Mapx}{\mathbf{x}}\newcommand{\Nml}{\mathbf{n}}$(Chapter 2, pp. 35 *ff*.) Let $(u, v)$ denote plane coordinates in some region, assume $x$, $y$, and $z$ are smooth, real-valued functions in this region, and write $\Mapx = (x, y, z)$ for the resulting surface parametrization. (We'll assume $\Mapx$ satisfies a *regularity* hypothesis that's convenient to defer briefly.)

That is, the surface we're starting from is parametrized by
$$
\Mapx(u, v) = \bigl(x(u, v), y(u, v), z(u, v)\bigr).
$$
For a graph, we may use a *Monge patch*, i.e., where $\Mapx(u, v) = \bigl(u, v, \phi(u, v)\bigr)$ for some function $\phi$.

The vector-valued partial derivatives
\begin{align*}
  \Mapx_{u} &= (x_{u}, y_{u}, z_{u}), \\
  \Mapx_{v} &= (x_{v}, y_{v}, z_{v})
\end{align*}
are tangent to the image of $\Mapx$. The regularity condition mentioned earlier is, at each point these vectors are linearly independent. In other words, the cross product $\Mapx_{u} \times \Mapx_{v}$ is nowhere-vanishing. (This is automatic for a Monge patch.) We define the *induced unit normal field* (p. 39) by
$$
\Nml := \frac{\Mapx_{u} \times \Mapx_{v}}{\lVert\Mapx_{u} \times \Mapx_{v}\rVert}.
$$

### Fundamental Forms

We define the components of the *first fundamental form* (p. 39) to be
\begin{align*}
  E &= \Mapx_{u} \cdot \Mapx_{u} = x_{u}^{2} + y_{u}^{2} + z_{u}^{2}, \\
  F &= \Mapx_{u} \cdot \Mapx_{v} = x_{u} x_{v} + y_{u} y_{v} + z_{u} z_{v}, \\
  G &= \Mapx_{v} \cdot \Mapx_{v} = x_{v}^{2} + y_{v}^{2} + z_{v}^{2}.
\end{align*}
(People also call these *metric components* in the given coordinates $(u, v)$, and use the notation $g_{ij}$, with $E = g_{11}$, $F = g_{12}$, and $G = g_{22}$.)

The functions $E$, $F$, and $G$ are defined even if $\Mapx$ is not regular. We have $0 \leq EG - F^{2}$ by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Lagrange's identity for the cross product takes the form $\lVert\Mapx_{u} \times \Mapx_{v}\rVert = \sqrt{EG - F^{2}}$. Consequently, regularity is equivalent to $0 < EG - F^{2}$, and if $\Mapx$ is regular we have
$$
\Nml = \frac{(y_{u}z_{v} - z_{u}y_{v}, z_{u}x_{v} - x_{u}z_{v}, x_{u}y_{v} - y_{u}x_{v})}{\sqrt{EG - F^{2}}}.
$$

We define the components of the *second fundamental form* (p. 46) to be
\begin{align*}
  \ell &= \Mapx_{uu} \cdot \Nml, \\
  m &= \Mapx_{uv} \cdot \Nml, \\
  n &= \Mapx_{vv} \cdot \Nml.
\end{align*}

### Christoffel Symbols

At each point of our surface, the vectors $\{\Mapx_{u}, \Mapx_{v}, \Nml\}$ are a basis of three-space. Consequently, every vector, such as $\Mapx_{uu}$ or $\Mapx_{uv}$ or $\Mapx_{vv}$, can be expressed as a linear combination of these basis elements. The normal components of the second derivatives are components of the second fundamental form. The tangential components are the *Christoffel symbols* (p. 57), defined by
\begin{alignat*}{3}
  \Mapx_{uu} &= \Gamma_{uu}^{u} \Mapx_{u} &&+ \Gamma_{uu}^{v} \Mapx_{v} &&+ \ell \Nml, \\
  \Mapx_{uv} &= \Gamma_{uv}^{u} \Mapx_{u} &&+ \Gamma_{uv}^{v} \Mapx_{v} &&+ m \Nml, \\
  \Mapx_{vv} &= \Gamma_{vv}^{u} \Mapx_{u} &&+ \Gamma_{vv}^{v} \Mapx_{v} &&+ n \Nml.
\end{alignat*}
The three matrix equations on p. 58 (double dagger symbol, see also below) express the Christoffel symbols in terms of the first fundamental form components and their first partials.

### Geodesic Equations

Every curve on our surface is the image of a curve $\bigl(u(t), v(t)\bigr)$ in the coordinate domain. A curve is a geodesic if and only if (p. 71, double clubsuit symbol) it satisfies the second-order non-linear ODE system
\begin{alignat*}{4}
  u''(t) &+ \Gamma_{uu}^{u} u'(t)^{2} &&+ 2\Gamma_{uv}^{u} u'(t) v'(t) &&+ \Gamma_{vv}^{u} v'(t)^{2} && = 0, \\
  v''(t) &+ \Gamma_{uu}^{v} u'(t)^{2} &&+ 2\Gamma_{uv}^{v} u'(t) v'(t) &&+ \Gamma_{vv}^{v} v'(t)^{2} && = 0.
\end{alignat*}

## Summary

Following this strategy, the task is in essence to

1. Calculate the Christoffel symbols in terms of the function $f$ whose graph is your surface of interest.
2. Solve the geodesic equations numerically, generating lists of $(u, v)$ values.
3. Plug the $(u, v)$ values into $\Mapx$, obtaining geodesics as curves on your surface.

Our surface is parametrized by
$$
\Mapx(u, v) = \bigl(x(u, v), y(u, v), z(u, v)\bigr).
$$
Calculate the three metric components
\begin{align*}
  E &= \Mapx_{u} \cdot \Mapx_{u} = x_{u}^{2} + y_{u}^{2} + z_{u}^{2}, \\
  F &= \Mapx_{u} \cdot \Mapx_{v} = x_{u} x_{v} + y_{u} y_{v} + z_{u} z_{v}, \\
  G &= \Mapx_{v} \cdot \Mapx_{v} = x_{v}^{2} + y_{v}^{2} + z_{v}^{2}.
\end{align*}
Calculate the six Christoffel symbols
\begin{align*}
  \left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
      \Gamma_{uu}^{u} \\
      \Gamma_{uu}^{v} \\
    \end{array}\right]
  &= \frac{1}{EG - F^{2}}\left[\begin{array}{@{}rr@{}}
      G & -F \\
      -F & E
    \end{array}\right]
  \left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
      \frac{1}{2}E_{u} \\
      F_{u} - \frac{1}{2}E_{v} \\
    \end{array}\right], \\
  %
  \left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
      \Gamma_{uv}^{u} \\
      \Gamma_{uv}^{v} \\
    \end{array}\right]
  &= \frac{1}{EG - F^{2}}\left[\begin{array}{@{}rr@{}}
      G & -F \\
      -F & E
    \end{array}\right]
  \left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
      \frac{1}{2}E_{v} \\
      \frac{1}{2}G_{u} \\
    \end{array}\right], \\
  %
  \left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
      \Gamma_{vv}^{u} \\
      \Gamma_{vv}^{v} \\
    \end{array}\right]
  &= \frac{1}{EG - F^{2}}\left[\begin{array}{@{}rr@{}}
      G & -F \\
      -F & E
    \end{array}\right]
  \left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
      F_{v} - \frac{1}{2}G_{u} \\
      \frac{1}{2}G_{v} \\
    \end{array}\right].
\end{align*}

For step 2., we can introduce formal parameters $(U, V) = (u', v')$. The second-order geodesic equations in two unknown functions $(u, v)$ become first-order equations in four unknown functions $(u, v, U, V)$:
\begin{align*}
  \left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
      u' \\
      v' \\
      U' \\
      V' \\
    \end{array}\right]
  &= \left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
      U \\
      V \\
      u'' \\
      v'' \\
    \end{array}\right] \\
  &= \left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
      U \\
      V \\
      -\Gamma_{uu}^{u}(u, v) U^{2} - 2\Gamma_{uv}^{u}(u, v) UV - \Gamma_{vv}^{u}(u, v) V^{2} \\
      -\Gamma_{uu}^{v}(u, v) U^{2} - 2\Gamma_{uv}^{v}(u, v) UV - \Gamma_{vv}^{v}(u, v) V^{2}
    \end{array}\right].
\end{align*}
Euler's method suffices to solve numerically; Desmos may be able to numerically solve ODE systems natively?

Step 3 is just a matter of evaluating $\Mapx$ at a set of data points.