# Approximating geodesics on some function f(x, y)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, geodesic

Note:
This is an update in a previous post that I think deserves it's own post as it's much more in-depth and is asking for assistance on a much less broad topic.

$^{\text{I'm putting these definitions here because I'm unsure if these notations are exclusive to Desmos or if it is widespread}}$
Definitions:
$L\left[n\right]$ where $L$ is a list:
element $n$ of list $L$
$A.c$ where $A$ is a coordinate point and $c$ is a coordinate axis: Value of the $\left(x, y, z\right)$ coordinate in point $A$

I've been with the Desmos calculator a lot and need some help with something I'm doing. I'm trying to find the geodesic of some function $f\left(x,y\right)$ as a manifold $M$ in 3D. The best way I've come up with to approximately trace a geodesic that I've come up with is using a ‘stepping’ method that uses something similar to the action command in Desmos, which looks like this:

$$ n \rightarrow \left[\text{action}\right]$$

‘[action]’ is the action you want to preform on the variable. this could be something like

$$n \rightarrow n+1$$

which would set the variable $n$ to whatever it's current value is +1. Using actions (which I will be referring to as iterations) could trace the approximate path of a geodesic if given a velocity $V$ and a starting point $P$. If we iterate $P$ by $V$, where $P$ is

$$\left(x_{1},y_{1},f\left(x_{1},y_{1}\right)\right)$$

and $V$ is

$$\left(V_{x},V_{y},f\left(V_{x},V_{y}\right)\right)$$

We then find the the point on our manifold $M$  closest to P which we will call $N$. We create an empty list $L =\begin{bmatrix} \space  \space \end{bmatrix}$ which we iterate as

$$L \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} P \space, N \end{bmatrix}$$

After we iterate $L$ we can iterate $P$ as $P \rightarrow N$. Now we subtract $L[1]$ and $L[2]$ which will give us our change in velocity $C$ so

$$
C.x=\left(L\left[1\right].x-L\left[2\right].x\right)\\[2mm] 
C.y=\left(L\left[1\right].y-L\left[2\right].y\right)\\[2mm]
C.z=\left(L\left[1\right].z-L\left[2\right].z\right)\\[2mm]
$$

which we then add iterate as our new vector  so $V \rightarrow C$
and we continue this for as long as we want to iterate it. The only part I can't figure out is how to find both the length of segment $\overline{\rm NP}$ and point $N$ . If you know how i could do this in Desmos

Comment: There is no such thing as a "geodesic of some function." Which book on differential geometry have you read?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I am not learning differential geo, I’m trying to approximate the geodesic between 2 points and extend that segment past the two points. if I need to correct anything just tell me what I need to change.

Comment: You would need to learn some differential geometry if you were to succeed with this. I do not even know what correction to suggest, it is too far off. Normally, one talks about geodesics on Riemannian surfaces. Your surface is most likely a regular surface in 3d space. What does it have to do with a function, I do not know. Maybe the surface is the graph of some smooth function.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Alright. I'm way in over my head with this project but I also enjoy it but I don't know anything about Riemannian surfaces. by the way, this is how $f$ is defined in desmos$$\begin{matrix}M=[…]\\C={[…]}\\B=[…]\\X_{1}=[…]\\Y_{1}=[…]\\\\f_1(a,b,c,x,y,x_1,y_1)=-a*b^{-{(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2\over c}}\\\\f_2(x,y,p_2)=f_1(M,B,C,x,y,X_1,Y_1)[p_2]\\\\s_1=\text{sort}(\text{length}(M,B,C,X_1,Y_1)[1]\\\\f(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{s_1}{f_2(x,y,n)}\\^{\text{Note: this summation doesn't work in Desmos so you would have to write out like }f_2(x,y,1)}\\^{f_2(x,y,2)\text{…until }f_2(x,y,s_1)}\end{matrix}$$

Comment: The good news is, if my guess regarding your [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4792499/geodesics-with-a-normal-distribution) is indeed correct, than what you're attempting looks achievable. The bad news is, (i) I don't know how to explain it without "magical formulas" coming from differential geometry; (ii) the proposed strategy has 4 or 5 major steps, and the details may be a little lengthy to write. <> If I were doing this myself I'd calculate as much by hand as possible. How much calculus exposure do you have?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I don't have a lot, but i can (i think)do partial and full derivatives and i can write out an integral, and maybe solve it. Multivariable calculus I cannot do integrals, and I don't know how to limits.

Comment: That's enough; we only need partial derivatives, perseverance, and Euler's method. I'll post at your other question since the mathematical answer better fits there.